# IIS 7.0 IIS Manager does not have the option "Manage Packages" available

Tags: iis, installation, package, microsoft-web-deploy

Trying to deploy a mvc package, but looking at the instructions here:
http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/07/importing-web-package-into-iis-manager.html

I do not see the "Manage Packages" option visible when I got to IIS Manager->Default Web Site
This is 2008R2 vanilla...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not an expert but have you install WebDeploy 2.0? (http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy)

Comment: thanks let me try that if thats makes any diffrence

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same problem. What I did to solve this in Windows 7 was:

- Go to Add or remove programs
- Search for Microsoft Web Deploy 2.0
- Uninstall it (it was already installed on my machine)
- Download the Microsoft Web Deploy 2.0 installation package [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=209115).
- Run the installer as Administrator
- Then go to Start -> Search programs and files and type `InetMgr.exe` hit enter and finally find the Deploy section under the Actions pane in IIS.